# TSOA FormField Array of String request

Tags: node.js, swagger, tsoa

I'm trying to generate a route that passes a file plus some additional parameters to a controller as follows:

```
myController(
@FormField() name: string,
@FormField() cnpj: string,
@FormField() sector: string,
@FormField() size: string,
@FormField() allowedDomains: string[], <-- Here the problem
@FormField() website?: string,
@UploadedFile() logo?: Express.Multer.File) {}
```

But one of these parameters is an array of strings (allowedDomains), and instead of being displayed as in the first image, it is generated according to the second.

[How its generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R0Sq.jpg)

[As I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYAZZ.jpg)

I've googled and look in the documentation, but I couldn't understand what's wrong. Directly changing the swagger file by adding an "items" property, works.

Comment: For now I've switched to sending the information in the body, and then the image is updated in another endpoint.
Would be nice to send all the data into a multipart form data, using a single endpoint and then tsoa document correctly =(